# JavaScript / ExtJs : TreePanel / TreeLoader : how to handle load errors?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Almost everything is in the title ;)

When you create a TreePanel you can add a loader this way:

```
loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
  dataUrl: '../myurl.php'
});
```

But how to handle load errors?

For example if the user is not connected I want to display a Login box.

I can't find an example showing how to handle loading errors with `TreeLoader` and/or `TreePanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the answer here;

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2072

Comment: Thank you very much this is a very very useful link I didn't find myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution: listeners.

Here's my code, I hope this will help someone!

```
loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    dataUrl: 'my_get_datas.php',
    listeners: {
        loadexception: function(tl, node, response) {
            if (response
            new WindowLoginPanel().show();
        }
    }
}),
```